# Infinite loop java

Tags: java, loops, infinite

**Problem specification:** Infinite loop ( menu enters an infinite loop );

**Objective:** Request user for an integer input and proceed in accordance to specified logic inside of the code. How to avoid the infinite loop?;

**Code:**

```
    public Purchase groceryStoreMenu(LemonadeStand lemonadeStand){

    boolean getMenu = true;
    int userEnteredNumber = -1;
    currentPurchase = new Purchase();

    while(getMenu){
         try{

           System.out.println("Grocery Store");
           System.out.printf("%s\t%s%n%s\t%s%n%s\t%s%n%s\t%s%n%s\t%s%n%s\t%s%n" , "1:" , "Buy lemons", "2:", "Buy cups" , "3:" , "Buy sugar" , 
           "4:" , "Buy ice" , "5:" , "Done"); //change this 
           userEnteredNumber = reader.nextInt();

           if (userEnteredNumber == 1 ) {
              money = lemonadeStand.profit(0);
              lemonsMenu(money);
           }else if (userEnteredNumber == 2){
              money = lemonadeStand.profit(0);
              cupsMenu(money); 
           }else if (userEnteredNumber == 3){
              money = lemonadeStand.profit(0);
              sugarMenu(money); 
           }else if (userEnteredNumber == 4){
               money = lemonadeStand.profit(0);
               iceMenu(money); 

           }else{
              money = lemonadeStand.profit(0);
             dailyGreetingMenu(); 

           }

        if (userEnteredNumber != 1 && userEnteredNumber !=2 && userEnteredNumber != 3 
            && userEnteredNumber != 4 && userEnteredNumber != 5) {
     throw new Exception(); 
    } else if(userEnteredNumber == 6) {
        getMenu = false;
        //break;
    } else {
        getMenu = false;
        //break;
    }

    }

    catch(Exception e) 
    {
        System.out.println("Error in number format. Enter a valid number from the choices (1,2,3,4,5,6)");
    }

    }


    return currentPurchase;
```

Comment: that formatting is just... terrible... I can barely read the code :/

Comment: reader.nextInt() probably isn't blocking.  I would start debugging there.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your program never reaches `if(userEnteredNumber == 6)` with 6 value, because if `userEnteredNumber` is 6, the first condition will grab it:

```
if (userEnteredNumber != 1 && userEnteredNumber !=2 && userEnteredNumber != 3 
        && userEnteredNumber != 4 && userEnteredNumber != 5) {
    throw new Exception(); 
}
```

then it throws exception, and it is `catch`ed within loop block. And any number other than 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6 is the same. So the loop never ends.

I don't like your code-style at all. But if you want to do it this way, you shall add `userEnteredNumber != 6` to first if condition.

Answer (score 0):

looks like the execution is never gonna enter the following block:
     else if(userEnteredNumber == 6) {
        getMenu = false;
        //break;
     }

the if condition should not contain '&&'.it should have been '||'
Also looks like you dont want your user to enter any number other than 1,2,3,4,5.

```
if (userEnteredNumber != 1 || userEnteredNumber !=2 || userEnteredNumber != 3 
        || userEnteredNumber != 4 || userEnteredNumber != 5) {
    getMenu = false;               
    throw new Exception();
}
```

Comment: Is this an answer or just an insulting commentary on the code?

Comment: I thought I provided an insight as well. what can i say.

Comment: Your answer is insulting, unsure, and doesn't clearly explain the answer.  If you're going to call the code terrible, please elaborate on why its terrible and provide a better alternative example.  When you say "I think it should have been..." you sound unsure.  If you're unsure, don't post an answer.

Comment: I removed the "terrible" word because it was very insulting but other people can use it in there comment thats ok

Comment: While I still don't completely agree with the comment, there's a difference between a generic "your code is terrible", and "your formatting is terrible".  Code is extraordinarily broad and gives the user no idea where to begin making his code less terrible.  Formatting, while still a little generic, is at least somewhat descriptive of the problem.